# why is $(this).data('mycontrol') undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Unfortunately my front end skills are lacking as my role puts me more on the server side / db technologies as opposed to css / js.  In any event, I am trying to implement this:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Complete-code-example-using-blueimp-jQuery-file-upload-control-in-Asp.Net.

And more specifically I was able to find an asp.net example here:

http://www.webtrendset.com/2011/06/22/complete-code-example-for-using-blueimp-jquery-file-upload-control-in-asp-net/

Basically allowing you to do mass image uploads.
I've set up the front end with the correct css and js files.  I had to modify some of the js files to make use of `on()` instead of `live()` as [live is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).  My form loads and looks like the following:

[image]

So far so good, however, as soon as I "Add file" or drag and drop a file chrome developer tools tells me the following:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_adjustMaxNumberOfFiles' of undefined`

It specifies the file as `jquery.fileupload-ui.js` and more specifically points me to this:

```
var that = $(this).data('fileupload');
that._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-data.files.length);
```

I `alert`ed `that` and of course it seems to be undefined...But I don't know enough jquery to understand why it is undefined.  My fileupload div markup was as follows:

```
   <div id="fileupload">
                         <form action="/Handler.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
                                <label class="fileinput-button">
                                    <span>Add files...</span>
                                    <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                                </label>
                                <button type="submit" class="start">Start upload</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="cancel">Cancel upload</button>
                                <button type="button" class="delete">Delete files</button>
                            </div>
                           </form>
                            <div class="fileupload-content">
                                <table class="files"></table>
                                <div class="fileupload-progressbar"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

So what could be causing this to be undefined?  This is what `_adjustMaxNumberOfFiles` does

```
  _adjustMaxNumberOfFiles: function (operand) {
            if (typeof this.options.maxNumberOfFiles === 'number') {
                this.options.maxNumberOfFiles += operand;
                if (this.options.maxNumberOfFiles < 1) {
                    this._disableFileInputButton();
                } else {
                    this._enableFileInputButton();
                }
            }
        },
```

**I'm using jquery 2.0.3 and jquery ui 1.10.3**

### Update

I've gotten it down to the point that the example link which I posted (2nd link above) the only difference is the version of jquery they are using, appears to be 1.8.2 and I am using 2.0.3.  The difference and problem is this piece of code:

`var that =  $(this).data('fileupload');`

In the example download this returns some strange object:

`a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) {element: e.fn.e.init[1], options: Object, _sequence: Object, _total: 0, _loaded: 0…}`

In my version (using 2.0.3) I am getting undefined for this:

`var that =  $(this).data('fileupload');`

Is there another way I can do this one line of code?

Comment: "Causing this to be undefined" - everything is undefined unless something defines it. Why do you think it *should* be defined?

Comment: Pointy I guess I don't know enough jquery to know why this is undefined.  I would assume $(this).data('fileupload') references my upload control, and having dropped a file in it (or more than one file in it) it would be defined?  I could be way off here.

Comment: where is your closing form tag?

Comment: As you might presume $(this) depends entirely on the context calling it. It may be that you intend: var that = $('#fileupload').data()

Comment: Maybe this would help you: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/2084

Comment: @VDesign copy / paste issue does that help. :)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: J.Wells as mentioned chrome.

Comment: ah - i missed that. Why not debug the js in chrome's dev tools?

Comment: JWells I am, however as you see in my post I am not certain why it is undefined.

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/2084

Comment: zsd see my edit 2.0.3.  zsd I tried all of those and nothing seems to be working for me :|.

Comment: Can anyone please help with this.  Why cant this line be translated `var that =  $(this).data('fileupload');` to get what I need via jquery 2.0.3? That is my only issue...Can someone explain what this line does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much playing around in the console window I got it with this:

`var that = $("#fileupload").data('blueimpUI-fileupload');`

So for anyone that is using anything > jQuery 1.8 please change this line:

`var that = $(this).data('fileupload');`

to this:

`var that = $("#fileupload").data('blueimpUI-fileupload');`

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was looking for. (And looks like the change would be needed in about 8 places.) Can you explain why this works? It looks like this returns the exact same results as the old version did with `$(this).data('fileupload')` but I don't understand why.

Comment: Also, wouldn't the code above change to `$(this).data('blueimpUI-fileupload');`?

Answer (score 0):

How are you initializing the plugin? The issue might be your selector. Target the form itself, vs. the wrapping div.

Based on your html...

Try changing: `$('#fileupload').fileupload({ /*options*/ });`

To: `$('#fileupload form').fileupload({ /*options*/ });`

Also, you may have to move your `.fileupload-content` div inside of the `form` tag as well.

Comment: Please look and download this link http://www.webtrendset.com/2011/06/22/complete-code-example-for-using-blueimp-jquery-file-upload-control-in-asp-net/ I am doing exactly the same as this example, the only difference is I have a newer version of jquery.What is erroring out for me is that `var that = $(this).data('fileupload')` is undefined...